Compiling assembly-code on ARMv7: CLang vs. GNU
I'm trying to build x265 on an ARMv7 system, and am getting the following error with one of the assembly-sources:
/usr/bin/c++ -mcpu=native -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -marm -DPIC -c .../source/common/arm/blockcopy8.S -o blockcopy8.S.o
.../source/common/arm/blockcopy8.S:835:21: error: expected immediate or register in shift operand

The compiler -- /usr/bin/c++ is clang-16.0.6. Using g++ 13.2.0 the same code compiles without a problem, which must be why the developers have never seen the problem.
The problematic line reads:
mov             r0, r0, lsr 16

How do I correct it so it compiles with clang just as well as it does with g++?

On my system, arm-none-eabi-as version 2.42 complains about that source line, Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix.  Since you have a GCC / GAS version that did assemble it, you could have used llvm-objdump -d or GNU objdump to see the canonical asm source version of it, lsr     r0, r0, #16 or mov  r0, r0, lsr #16

Seems like it disassembles to lsr     r0, r0, #16 indeed. Is that, what I should be using -- would it be correct for both GNU and CLANG? Or should I use your other variant, the mov  r0, r0, lsr #16? Thanks!

Both will assemble to the same machine code.  I'd use lsr since that's easier for humans to read.  In Thumb mode, there is an actual lsr opcode separate from mov, although this instruction is still 4 bytes and requires Thumb2.  In ARM mode, assemblers translate lsr to mov with a flexible source operand for you.

Thanks, @PeterCordes -- why don't you make a proper answer so I can accept it?

I didn't answer since I was looking for a duplicate.  Found one that discusses it without mentioning clang:  Is the hash required for immediate values in ARM assembly? - I had just put the source line in a file by itself, without .syntax unified, so that's why GAS gave me an error message about it, too.  IDK how easily future readers will find this with a very generic title.

And now there is a new problem :-/

On My POV: error you're encountering is due to a difference in how Clang and GCC handle certain ARM assembly syntax. The line that's causing the issue is:
mov             r0, r0, lsr 16

This syntax is using the "flexible second operand" feature of ARM assembly, which GCC accepts but Clang doesn't in this context. To make it compatible with both compilers, you need to use a more explicit syntax that Clang understands.
Here's how you can modify the line to work with both Clang and GCC:
lsr             r0, r0, #16

This modification does the exact same thing (logical shift right by 16 bits) but uses a syntax that both compilers understand. The lsr instruction is explicitly used instead of relying on the flexible second operand of mov.
It's worth noting that this is a known difference between GCC and Clang in handling ARM assembly. If you're able to, you might want to report this issue to the x265 developers so they can update their assembly code to be compatible with both compilers.

GCC/GAS and Clang's built-in assembler both accept the flexible second way of writing it, mov  r0, r0, lsr #16.  Clang is just stricter about requiring # on immediate constants, like later GAS (2.42 reports Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix).

(Correction to my prev comment, GAS only requires # in "divided" syntax mode, which is the default but almost everyone uses .syntax unified at the top of their ARM source files.  Clang requires # even in unified mode.  See Is the hash required for immediate values in ARM assembly?)  This answer is still incorrect in claiming that Clang doesn't accept flexible second operand, unless older Clang versions rejected it for mov (or were very incomplete!)  Clang 18.1.8 on my system assembles the mov ..., lsr #16 version.

Submitted the bug-report.
